# Bound on a probability regarding the sum of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Assume that we have two random variables $X$ and $Y$. Also assume that:

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}(X\leq1)\geq 1 - \epsilon \\ \mathbb{P}(Y\leq2)\geq 1 - \epsilon
\end{equation}
Does it generally hold that 
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}(X +Y\leq3)\geq 1 - 2\epsilon 
\end{equation} 
Thanks for any help!

Comment: What have you tried?  How do the events $\{X+Y>3\}$ and $\{X>1\}\cup\{Y>2\}$ compare?

Comment: First is included on the second right?

Comment: Well, how can you prove that?  And what can you do with it?

Comment: I use contradiction to prove it and then I can get an inequality for the probabilities. Ok, got it.

Answer (score 0):

$p(x+y \leq 3) \geq p(x \leq 1 \cap y \leq 2)
 = 1 - p(x > 1 \cup y > 2) \geq 1 - p(x > 1) - p(y > 2) \geq 
 1 - 2\epsilon$

Comment: I am a bit confused by the inequality $1 - p(x > 1 \cup y > 2) \geq 1 - p(x > 1) - p(y > 2)$ - X and Y have two separate probability measures so you can't apply subadditivity. You need to consider the joint probability distribution in this case.

Comment: $p(a \cup b) \leq p(a) + p(b)$